# Diffie-Hellman on additive group

Tags: diffie-hellman, group-theory

Given the finite cyclic, additive group (G, +), with |G| = n and generator = g, what are the computations and exchanged messages for Diffie-Hellman?

What I tried myself:

- Alice chooses a private $a$ and sends $p(|G|)$ and $g$ (generator) to Bob.
- Alice calculates $A = a\cdot g  \mod p (|G|)$ and sends it to Bob.
- Bob chooses a private $b$ and calculates $B = b \cdot g \mod p (|G|)$ and sends it back to Alice.
- Alice calculates $a \cdot B \mod p (|G|)$ which is the shared key.
- Alice calculates $b \cdot A \mod p (|G|)$ which is the shared key.

Is this way of thinking correct? Because I'm not sure because the group is additive.

Comment: In the beginning you write that the oder of $G$ is $n$ and then you switch to $p$ (or to be precise a strange notation $\pmod{p~|G|}$ which does not make sense)? Furthermore, your write-up does not use the notation of additive groups (but multiplicative ones).

Comment: How should I change it to use the the additive groups then?

Comment: Additive vs. multiplicative is only a difference in notation. Replace multiplication with addition and exponentiation with scalar multiplication.

Comment: But if you use addition modulo a prime, that's a bad idea, since the discrete logarithm problem in that group is easy.

Comment: @Matthias_164: Is $G$ just an arbitrary group or the integers modulo $N$ (in which case it's probably simpler to rewrite in that notation)

Comment: G is a finite cyclic group. @figlesquidge

Comment: @CodesInChaos Then what would be the computations and exchanged messages for this cyclic, additive group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the additive group $(G, +)$ with $|G| = p$ and generator $P$, what are the computations and exchanged messages for Diffie-Hellman?

I use order $p$ and assuming $p$ to be prime and the generator as $P$ (as it is used in context of elliptic curve groups - since you need additive groups where the DLP and the CDHP are hard - which is not the case for $\mathbb{Z}_n$).

- Alice chooses random $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ and sends $A=aP$ (this means $P+\ldots+P$, $a$ times).
- Bob chooses  $b\in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ and sends $B=bP$.
- Alice computes $K=aB=(ab)P$
- Bob computes $K=bA=(ba)P=(ab)P$

Note that since I assume that we work on elliptic curve groups there is no reduction modulo the group order after the additive operation.